# Reading data of a DataContext object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question is regarding this NodeJS + ReactJS application I am modifying. I was able to do some modifications, but given my limited React knowledge, I was not able to do the below. Here is the application on Gitub: https://github.com/nice-table/bitmex-scaled-orders

I am inside the file "src/modules/orders/OrderForm.js" and trying to access the "positions" data (which I suppose is handled in the file "src\modules\data\DataProvider.js"). That same position data is rendered in this file: "src/containers/Dashboard/PositionsTable.js"

How can I have the "positions" data accessible from the OrderForm file? The same data being rendered in the PositionsTable.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code, `OrderForm` component uses `UISettingsContext.Consumer` and `PositionsTable` uses `DataContext.Consumer`, so if you want to pass `positions` to the `OrderForm` components, you'll have to combine those 2 consumers like this:

```js
<UISettingsContext.Consumer>
{settingsData => (
  <DataContext.Consumer>
  {dataContext => (
    <OrderForm
      instrumentData={settingsData.getCurrentInstrumentData()}
      currentInstrument={settingsData.currentInstrument}
      positions={dataContext.getAllPositions()}
      createOrders={createBulkOrders.doFetch}
    />
  )}
  </DataContext.Consumer>
)}
</UISettingsContext.Consumer>
```

Of course you'll have to modify `OrderForm` component to accept a `positions` props like this:

```
function OrderForm({ positions, currentInstrument, instrumentData, createOrders }) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When shall I add the that new UISettingsContext code exactly?

Comment: If you check inside [src/containers/Dashboard/index.js](https://github.com/nice-table/bitmex-scaled-orders/blob/7a6a2f9c4f6ec1d317ab7647e61b1d32822f509b/src/containers/Dashboard/index.js#L71) at **line 71**, you'll see how `UISettingsContext` is used. You will add it there you want to use the `OrderForm` component of course.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tried to replace the one there with the new one, but it gave me compile error: Line 81:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: Nevermind, you had a missing ). I think its fixed. Will try now.

Comment: Yes, there was a missing closing parenthesis, I have corrected this syntax error.

Comment: A followup question: say I want to monitor (real-time) the value from that position object inside OrderForm page and if say it hits a specific value, I want to show an alert or Submit the form on that page. How to do that?

Comment: Infact, I want specifically this value "unrealisedPnl" which is inside PositionsTable.js to be monitored (as it is coming in real-time from the NodeJS server. If that value reaches a specific number, I want to "submit" the form in "OrderForm.js". How could it be done?

Comment: I think I need to use "onChange" but I am not sure where and how to insert. Would appreciate your help with it, thanks.